# ASP.net / Javascript: Automatically postback triggering and next control to have focus

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, event-handling, focus

I will preface my question with the disclaimer that I am fairly new to ASP and VB programming and not yet exposed to all the language and framework have to offer.

I am building an ASP site using VB, and I have specific requirements to follow.  In the section of the form in question, a series of text boxes collects quantities of an item.  Upon postback, the quantities are used to recalculate a total.  All of these controls perform the calculation perfectly.

For this form, I am using the OnChange Javascript event to trigger the postback when any of them are modified.  This also works correctly.  However, when the user clicks or tabs away from the textbox being changed and the postback fires, no control appears to have focus.

I need the focus to be on the control which was clicked by the user, if they clicked onto another control.  Is there an event or method by which I can capture the ID of the control which gained focus immediately prior to the postback being triggered?  I have seen several questions and answers which demonstrate how to collect the ID of the control which actually triggered the postback, but this would place the focus directly back into the field which was just changed.

Whether the focus is placed into the control which triggered the postback or not, the behavior requires the user to select their next control twice, once to indirectly fire the postback and once to place focus into the desired control.

Comment: Take a look at these two questions I already asked. [First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095444/fire-an-event-after-the-barcode-reading-and-to-set-focus-on-textbox) one is about setting focus after some keystroke is type, and [second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221089/how-to-fire-an-event-when-the-tab-key-is-pressed) is related to catch the "tab" stroke and trigger an event just after.

Comment: Do you have any code you can show? Also, why postback on every control?

Comment: I will post relevant code shortly, but I am only firing a postback on each of the textboxes which were changing and only due to my inexperience with the .Net framework.  The answer regarding using the UpdatePanel is the "right" answer for the postback question, but I am still having trouble with the JavaScript autofiring the .click method of the hidden button I created to trigger the UpdatePanel's refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm understanding you completely, but I've tried to recreate your scenario from your description, and using an UpdatePanel looks like a simple solution. This is a quick and easy way of ajaxifying your page, without worrying about the details. Surround the field that is being updated with the UpdatePanel, and add an AsyncPostBackTrigger for the control (or controls) that cause the postback (in this case, a hidden button):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pb() {
        document.getElementById("<%= btnPostBack.ClientID %>").click();
    }
</script>
<asp:button id="btnPostBack" runat="server" onclick="PostBack" style="display: none;" />

<asp:textbox id="t1" runat="server" onchange="pb();" />
<asp:textbox id="t2" runat="server" onchange="pb();" />
<asp:textbox id="t3" runat="server" onchange="pb();" />
<asp:textbox id="t4" runat="server" onchange="pb();" />

<asp:updatepanel id="update" runat="server">
    <contenttemplate>
        <asp:label id="label" runat="server" />
    </contenttemplate>
    <triggers>
        <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="btnPostBack" />
    </triggers>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

In my PostBack method in code behind, I simply aggregate the values from t1, t2, t3 and t4. I can tab from one TextBox to the next adding text, and the label is updated without focus being lost.

Comment: I like this solution, and I have implemented it as you have suggested.  I have created a short javascript using getElementByID in my aspx file, and I have wrapped the pricing controls in an UpdatePanel with the AsyncPostBackTrigger as suggested.  However, the onchange event isn't firing, despite being present on the text boxes containing the values being tallied.  Testing the UpdatePanel, I turned off the inline CSS to view the button on the page.  When I change of the boxes in question, the UpdatePanel fires as expected.  The JavaScript events do not fire, though.

Comment: This answer is working, except for a change of strategy...  I had already created TextChanged event handlers for each of the textboxes in question when I was trying to leverage OnBlur and set focus on a control dynamically.  I simply added each of the controls as additional triggers in the UpdatePanel definition.  I also removed my previous OnTextChanged attribute from my control definitions and replaced that with AutoPostBack = True.  Now, each control does post back asynchronously to the panel.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that's how I would have done it too. I only used javascript and the hidden button because it sounded like that might be how you were doing it.